# How to Pass Eval Values from inside Repeaters in ASP.NET Webforms to a JavaScript Function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

I am very new to working with `javascript` and `asp.net` webforms. Below is a repeater I am using where I am simply trying to pass a value from the repeater to a javascript function as a parameter...In no way I am being able to do this. Below is the code of the repeater and the javascript function that i want to pass the value as a parameter

`webform`

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RpTopProduct" runat="server" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div style="text-align: right; margin-top: 10px;">
            <asp:Button Text="Add To Cart" runat="server" OnClientClick='<%# 
                String.Format("javascript:return openNavFromInsideOrderList(\"{0}\")",
                    Eval("ProductName").ToString()) %>' />
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

`javascript`

```
function openNavFromInsideOrderList(ProductName) {
    console.log(ProductName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`OnClientClick` calls a JavaScript function, so you don't have to say 'javascript' inside `String.Format`. I think you can simplify it quite a bit.

Untested:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RpTopProduct" runat="server" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div style="text-align: right; margin-top: 10px;">
            <asp:Button Text="Add To Cart" runat="server" OnClientClick='<%# 
                String.Format("openNavFromInsideOrderList(\"{0}\")",
                    Eval("ProductName")) %>' />
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

To stop a postback:

```
...
... String.Format("openNavFromInsideOrderList(\"{0}\"); return false;",
    Eval("ProductName")) %>' />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just put in the server side eval like this:

```
OnClientClick="openNavFromInsideOrderList('abc');return false" />
```

Now, the above is hard coded. You don't note if code behind is vb or c#.

So the ONLY part in above we would want to replace is the abc with a eval() - the rest will be as per above.

If this is a number, then we don't need quotes around the Eval(). But for a string, we need at least single (or double) quotes either ("abc") or ('abc').

So, a eval could/would look like this:

```
 OnClientClick = '<%# "myjstest(" + Chr(34) + Eval("HotelName") + Chr(34) + ");return false;" %>'
```

Or, in your case say this:

```
 OnClientClick =
  '<%# "openNavFromInisideOrderList(" + Chr(34) + Eval("ProductName") + Chr(34) + ");return false;" %>'
```

The above server expression is vb, but you get the idea. So you don't need javascipt tags or anything. You just need a string expression that eventually resolves to this:

```
OnClientClick = "openNavFromInisideOrderList('My cool Product name');return false;"
```